# Should Actions in Redux always be unique?

Tags: redux

In this example I'm using an action named **ADD_TODO**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';

function todos(state, action) {
    state = state || [];
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            return state.concat([ action.text ]);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

function counter(state, action){
    state = state || 0;
    switch (action.type){
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return state+1;
        case 'DECREMENT':
            return state-1;
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            return state+100;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

var app = combineReducers({
    todos: todos,
    counter: counter
});

var store = createStore(app);
store.dispatch({ type: 'ADD_TODO': text: 'buy eggs' });
```

This cause both the "**todos**" and "**counter**" reducers to trigger.
Should I make all reducers have unique actions unless I actually intended it?

How can we implement this with multiple reducers that almost do the same thing? Multiple counters for example can have "INCREMENT" and a "DECREMENT" actions.

Should name spacing actions solve it?

> eg: "POINT_INCREMENT", "POINT_DECREMENT".

Comment: Related - [How to dispatch an action to a specific reducer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48395566/104380)

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing inherently wrong with having different reducers respond to the same action -- for example, if you refresh the entire state at once. But yeah, if you have two counters that correspond to different things, you probably want to come up with a naming scheme to differentiate. But I would think the action names probably should have some noun to indicate what they apply to.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. OP doesn't have "two  counters" as you've mentioned. he has two separate reducers, both using the same *action* name, so when he `dispatch` the `ADD_TODO` action, both are triggered. This means the **Redux**'s state is technically flat when wanting fire a specific state change for a specific reducer which shares the same `action.type` as another reducer

Comment: @vsync OP specifically mentioned the possibility of having multiple counters: `Multiple counters for example can have "INCREMENT" and a "DECREMENT" actions.`

Answer (score 0):

> This cause both the "todos" and "counter" reducers to trigger. Should I make all reducers have unique actions unless I actually intended it?

Yes, probably they should have different unique actions.
From your example it becomes not really clear what you actually intend.
Should the counter count the amount of todo's ?
In that case it can actually be sensible that a "ADD_ITEM" action would both update the counter and also add a todo item. In that case please refer to the answer of acjay

> How can we implement this with multiple reducers that almost do the same thing? Multiple counters for example can have "INCREMENT" and a "DECREMENT" actions.

When displaying a list of counters in the same app, each counter can be assigned a unique identifier (id).
An action should pass along the id of the counter.

```
export const toggleTodo = id => ({
  type: 'INCREMENT',
  id
})
```

The reducer should then check by id which counter to update.
See this example of a todo list in the official redux docs.
https://redux.js.org/basics/example

Redux actions are in a way globals. There are different strategies to workaround this problem on a larger scale.
https://kickstarter.engineering/namespacing-actions-for-redux-d9b55a88b1b1