# How to dispatch an action to a specific reducer？

Tags: react-redux

I have multiple reducers, each has a type 'INIT'. What I want to achieve is only the relevant reducer can receive the action, judging from where the action was triggered. Is there any middleware can do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

Are you re-using reducer logic while creating reducers?

You can try something like of this :-

```
function createCounterWithNamedType(counterName = '') {
    return function counter(state = 0, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case `INCREMENT_${counterName}`:
                return state + 1;
            case `DECREMENT_${counterName}`:
                return state - 1;
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
}


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    counterA : createCounterWithNamedType('A'),
    counterB : createCounterWithNamedType('B'),
    counterC : createCounterWithNamedType('C'),
});

store.dispatch({type : 'INCREMENT_B'});
console.log(store.getState());
```

This is something called Higher Order Reducers in which you can use same reducer logic by creating a wrapper function as shown above in the code above.

You can check more about Higher Order Reducers [here](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ReusingReducerLogic.html)

Comment: This basically means REDUX is flat if viewed from the perspective of the `dispatch` context

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so you can do it that way.

> Usually I would have unique type for each reducers and if I need to use the same action for more than one reducers,
>    I will use the combine Reducer functionality to achieve the same.